# Make methods work independently without using a common method

Tags: c#, .net

I am currently trying to separate out the method implementation so that they can work independently. The methods that I am trying to separate are store and checker. Both these methods require the traverse method. My current implementation has two method store and checker methods which I have separated them into different classes. They require to be called within the traverse method to work. This is the my current implementation.

```
class Traverse
{
    public void traversemethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Traverse function");
        Checker r = new Checker();
        r.checkermethod();
        Store s = new Store();
        s.storemethod();
    }
}

class Checker
{
    public void checkermethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Checker function");            
    }
}

class Store
{
    public void storemethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Store function");
    }
}

class Compute
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Main function");
        Traverse v = new Traverse();
        v.traversemethod();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Is there any way by which I can implement them separately without declaring them together in traverse method and calling both store and checker method separately in the main function. I can implement the traverse method in both store and checker method, but i was wondering if there is any way to do it rather than duplicating the same code again.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're asking here. How do you want to change it?

Comment: Please be more clear on what your need is. what is the problem of calling the store and checker method from your main function in your current implementation?

Comment: @TimS.@Omribitan Both the store and checker method needs to traverse through an array, which makes traverse common to both. I can get it to work by including the traverse code in both store and checker to call both store and checker independently in main(). My query is there any other way that I can use to achieve the same result without copying the "traverse" code for every method I implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not about the relationship between `Checker` and `Store` so I'll show an example with an `interface` instead of a base class. However you could create a base class, possibly abstract, and have each child class implement their special method.

```
interface IPerformMethod    
{
   void SpecialFunction();
}

public class Store : IPerformMethod
{
   public void SpecialFunction()
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Store function");
   }
}

public class Checker : IPerformMethod
{
   public void SpecialFunction()
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Checker function"); 
   }
}
```

Then in your `TraverseMethod`, you could pass in an object that implements `IPerformMethod` (in this case it's either an instance of `Checker` or `Store`).

```
public void TraverseMethod(IPerformMethod item)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Traverse function");
   item.SpecialFunction();
}

//To call the method 
TraverseMethod(new Checker());
TraverseMethod(new Store());
```

(Obviously you can rename the `IPerformMethod` interface to something more descriptive but if I understand the question correctly, this seems to be what you want).

Comment: when i try to implement the above code I am unable to define the parameter within the TraverseMethod as IPerfromMethod type. is there anything that I could have possibly done wrong.

Comment: It's hard to tell without code. I'm not sure if your comment is a typo, but it should be `IPerformMethod` not `IPerfromMethod`. If that's not it then make sure your interface is accessible to the class.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a perfect place to use a lambda:

```
public delegate void TraverseDelegate();
public void traversemethod(TraverseDelegate dlg){
    Console.WriteLine("Traverse function");
    dlg();
}
```

and in the `Main` method use:

```
Traverse v = new Traverse();
v.traversemethod(() => {
    Checker r = new Checker();
    r.checkermethod();
    Store s = new Store();
    s.storemethod();
});
```

### EDIT/UPDATE(=UPDIT :-) )

You can also make the delegate a member field of `Traverse`, and then pass it as a constructor argument and call `traversemethod` without any arguments:

```
public class Traverse{
    public delegate void TraverseDelegate();
    private TraverseDelegate dlg;

    public Traverse(TraverseDelegate dlg){
        this.dlg=dlg;
    }

    public void traversemethod(){
        Console.WriteLine("Traverse function");
        dlg();
    }
}
```

and in the `Main` method use:

```
Traverse v=new Traverse(()=>{
        Checker r = new Checker();
        r.checkermethod();
        Store s = new Store();
        s.storemethod();
});
v.traversemethod();
```

Comment: Does the traversemethod() take any argument?? As I keep getting an error which says that the method has no overload and takes 1 argument.

Comment: Notice that in my first code-snippet I declared `traversemethod` to take a `delegate` argument. If you don't want `traversemethod` to take any arguments, you could also pass the delegate in `Traverse`'s constructor(I'll update the answer with that approach).

Comment: I am totally new to lambda, now it flags an expected "class, enum, struct" error at new traverse, new checker & new store in main

Comment: Can you update the question with your code that tries to use lambdas? Or make a [gist](http://gist.github.com/) or something.

Comment: Here is the link to the code that I am trying to run https://gist.github.com/ajitpeter/6547444

Comment: The problem is that you moved the `Main` method out of the `Compute` class and into the global scope - which is illegal in C#, where methods must be declared inside classes.

Comment: I was still in the C++ mindset :-) both of the answers work as my requirement.